# How to edit the DIV which renders only runtime. which is not present in HTML page?

Tags: html, dom

I have a small web app which has `<a href=">` tag which renders the only runtime I mean it does not appear in HTML page it appears only in chrome developers tools. How to eliminate such kind a tag and override or edit it.

I tried editing code via its script when I inspected for long it split `document.querySelector("#m360CrA483349594983")` but when I search entire project there's no sign of it!

```
<a href="" onclick="this.blur();" target="_blank" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;" id="m360CrA374595840089">demos written can be eliminated for sure!</a>
```

Even I tried to Enable Local Overrides on but nothing seems to work that mysterious tag is kept coming saying

> "demos written can be eliminated for sure!"

Comment: I guess this tag appears through an extension of your browser or you are using a library/plugin that does it. Try in incognito mode with your browsers without any extension enabled.

Comment: @jose i dont use any plugin or cdn its some js mixed html but that js is kind a uncompressed v cant read he scipt

Comment: have you tested in incognito mode or in another browser like Firefox if this tag appears?

Comment: yep tried every where it displays. btw this is head part: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Magi</title>

<link href="magi/magi.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="magi/magi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Please attach the code of `magi/magi.js` because you say that you tried in another browser, and you don't have any plugin or library. The only way that it can occur that is through this script. At least I'm thinking that

Comment: @Jose Silva Kindly Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/32snj9Lu/             This is that magi.js

Comment: I can't see the link that you mentioned in the `jsfiddle` script

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/praveenss/8fd2k47q/1/

Answer (score 1):

once the dom is ready you can access the element

```html
<script>
  (function() {
    // the DOM will be available here
    document.getElementById("m360CrA483349594983");

  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [body onload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event listener in order to search for tag appearing at runtime.

Also, pay attention to tag ID value, it seems it is generated every time, so, you won't be able to find it by static ID

Comment: Yes you are rite it generates new id every time page Load like incresing last two digits how to eliminate it